# Expliquer la différence entre « parler à » et « parler avec »

Tags: sens, prépositions

Comment expliquer à un étudiant la différence entre *parler à* et *parler avec* ?

Existe-t-il une règle pour savoir quand il faut utiliser l'un ou l'autre ?

Comment: J'ai changé *parlé de* en *parler à* puisque c'est de ce dernier dont il s'agit dans le corps de la question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez OK merci il s'agissait d'une erreur de ma part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Parler avec* suggère une conversation, *parler à* est plus unidirectionnel, même s'il y a conversation, l'accent est mis sur la participation du sujet.